# 同一バッファで、別々の箇所を別々の window で narrowing するには？

Tags: emacs

ある org ファイルに対して、 `org-narrow-to-subtree` を、別々の subtree で実行し、
それを別々のウィンドウで表示したいと思いました。

これを実現するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。

現状、片一方で narrowing した時点で、もう一方の window でも narrowing されてしまいます。

Comment: 上手く行くかどうか分かりませんが、`clone-indirect-buffer-other-window(C-x 4 c)` が使えるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`M-x clone-indirect-buffer-other-window`(<kbd>C-x 4 c</kbd>)で、 org-narrow-to-subtree を別々に行えることを確認しました。